Как лучше всего хранить в бд такие данные?
Мне нужно хранить в бд данные, вида:
    {
        'Heading': [
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        ..., 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an]
        ],
        'Disclosure': [
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        ..., 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an]
        ],
        'Measure_unit': [
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        ..., 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an]
        ],
        'Quantity': [
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        ..., 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an]
        ],
        'Code': [
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an], 
                        ..., 
                        [a1, a2, ..., an]
        ]
    }

Эти данные нужны для поиска, также кроме этих данных есть и те, которые хранятся в обычном списке (например имя организации). Нужно чтобы структура бд была примерно такой:
Имя, Описание, Адрес, и по одному списку из Heading, Disclosure, и т.д.
Ссылка на примеры данных:
https://etender.gov.az/main/competition/detail/316641

Выглядит как json, но вы лучше расскажите, что конкретно вы хотите и какая задача у вас (и почему вы решили, что для вашей задачи нужен mysql вообще)

Все зависит от того, зачем вам это и что вы с ними планируете делать в будущем? Можно все это просто свалить в одно поле, можно разложить по отдельным полям. Можно вытащить даже значения массива в отдлельную таблицу. Т.е. что бы понять "как лучше", надо понять "зачем" и "для чего"

Как именно будут использоваться эти данные? Только получение сохранённого, целиком как записано? Или нужна какая-то обработка (сравнение, поиск, получение отдельных составляющих)?

@andreymal Я пропарсил сайт(таблицу в нем), и там кроме этих данных есть и те, которые можно просто хранить в обычном списке(например имя организации), и каждая из элементов из Heading,  Disclosure и т.д. была вместе с одним элементом из других данных, например:
Имя, Описание, Адрес,  список из "Heading", список из "Disclosure'", список из "Measure_unit", список из "Quantity", список из "Code"

@Akina Эти данные нужны для поиска

Эти данные нужны для поиска Тогда покажите реальное значение, которое требуется сохранять (конечно, списки можно сократить до 2-3 элементов на массив), и несколько примеров наборов критериев для поиска.

@Akina "реальное значение, которое требуется сохранять", Хорошо, добавлю в вопрос. А про наборы критериев для поиска не совсем понял.

про наборы критериев для поиска не совсем понял Что не понял-то? Ну не может же быть просто "найди что-нибудь", верно? есть какие-то значения, которые должны быть в том, что нужно найти. Например, "в параметре Disclosure не менее чем в 2 массивах имеется значение 123".И нужно именно значение, а не его отображение на веб-странице.

Меня очень смущает, что структура данных по ссылке не совпадает со структурой данных, которую вы показали в вопросе — это может намекать на то, что вы написали какой-то ну запредельно кривой парсер, который делает запредельно странные вещи. Ну или я чего-то не понимаю или вы чего-то не дообъяснили

@andreymal Можете привести пример такой структуры(какой она должна быть)?
"это может намекать на то, что вы написали какой-то ну запредельно кривой парсер", я парсил данные из таблицы с помощью GET запросов с помощью requests, не думаю что это из-за кривизны парсера

@Akina Я хотел проводить частичный поиск с помощью LIKE т.е. например, в ссылке вопроса(пример данных) вводишь "Pəncərə tipli kondisioner"("Heading"), и тебе выводит каждый ряд в бд где есть этот запрос(с помощью WHERE).

@KibarJafarguliyev в html-коде страницы по ссылке из вопроса в принципе нету никакой таблицы, вы не могли парсить несуществующую таблицу через requests, то есть вы что-то не договариваете

@andreymal Заходите в ту ссылку, жмите f12 -> Network(Сеть) -> Fetch/XHR(обновите страницу) -> среди тех файликов выберите https://etender.gov.az/api/events/316641/bomLines?PageSize=6&PageNumber=1 , там вся информация о таблице будет указана в json формате

@KibarJafarguliyev воот, и этот json абсолютно не похож на те данные, которые вы показали в тексте вопроса

@andreymal Я после получения того json-a создал словарь в котором создал Heading и т.д., а вот то что в каждом элементе словаря по несколько элементов объясняется тем, что там не одна страница, и это значит что один влож. список в элементах словаря на одну страницу

@KibarJafarguliyev а зачем вводить лишнюю сущность под названием «страница»? Есть объект под названием «тендер», у него есть список объектов под названием «элемент тендера» — всё, никаких «страниц» не надо

Из json-ов на сайте естественным образом вытекает структура наподобие CREATE TABLE tender (id INTEGER, rfxid INTEGER, tenderName TEXT, organizationName TEXT и так далее) и CREATE TABLE tenderItem (id INTEGER, tenderId INTEGER, name TEXT, description TEXT, unitOfMeasure TEXT и так далее) — и после этого сразу же естественным образом получаются всякие поиски вида SELECT id, tenderId FROM tenderItem WHERE name LIKE '%Pəncərə tipli kondisioner%' (вопрос производительности пока что опускаю для краткости). А то, что вы понаписали в тексте вопроса, какое-то странное и непонятное

@andreymal Так сам объект "тендер" со своими списками объектов  находится в "странице" откуда и берем гет запрос

@KibarJafarguliyev «страница» — это всего лишь способ сэкономить трафик и время путём отображения ограниченной выборки строк из таблицы «тендер». В самой базе данных никаких «страниц» разумеется нету, выборка конкретной страницы делается через WHERE/OFFSET/LIMIT

@andreymal Это же только для одного тендера, на сайте их около 3000, будет ли необходимость создавать влож. таблицы?

@KibarJafarguliyev если предположить, что в одном тендере таблица содержит не более 20 элементов, то на 3000 тендеров будет всего 60000 элементов — это вообще микроскопическая нагрузка, двух вышеупомянутых мной таблиц будет более чем достаточно (ну ещё с индексами и полнотекстовым поиском стоит поиграться, но я этот вопрос пока опускаю для краткости)

@andreymal Поэтому и спрашиваю будет ли необходимость создавать влож. таблицы?

@KibarJafarguliyev ладно, если вы настаиваете — что такое «влож. таблицы»?

@andreymal Понял, спасибо большое, попробую поиграться с этим)

@andreymal я имел ввиду связанные таблицы. В бд на один ряд нельзя много значений добавлять(связь 1:N) и влож. таблицы означают таблицы для хранения их значений (id_parent,value)

@KibarJafarguliyev ну в вышеупомянутом мной примере между таблицами tender и tenderItem подразумевается связь 1:N (где tenderItem.tenderId это внешний ключ на tender.id)

Поэтому я и поблагодарил за помощь

Я специализируюсь на базах данных, поэтому замечу, что ошибки планирования стоят дороже всего когда-нибудь потом. Этот тот самый случай. Если подойти формально, без вникания в смысл названий, то очевидно, что "Heading" и компания - таблицы, a1, a2, ..., an - числовые поля, а [a1, a2, ..., an] - строки данных. Замечу также, что an в базах данных, если по уму, возникает только в случае использования n-го количества строк, а не видов полей.
Само по себе использование баз данных, особенно когда речь идёт о миллионах записей, как здесь пишут, не проблема, а вопрос удобства и опыта. Мне, например, удобнее и быстрее писать код для базы данных sqlite3, чем разбираться в какой-то мути типа панды, сопровождая всё это километрами кода.

А вы точно специализируетесь на базах данных..?

Это что-то сравнимое  с профессией астронавта? Я начинаю собой гордиться... Я программирую базы данных с 1995 года. Хватит?

Ну тогда вы должны знать, что sqlite довольно специфическая база данных с кучей нюансов и используют её либо новички, либо при особой нужде

А что, задача какая особо умная? Кто говорил о серверной базе данных и большом уме? "...база данных с кучей нюансов и используют её либо новички, либо при особой нужде..." - ни о чём, говорильня, лишь бы что. Минуснули, кстати, Вы? 5:1

обычно, когда пишут a1, a2, an речь идет не о трех элементах. Предлагаете создать таблицу с N столбцов, где N вполне может быть сотней? И рядышком где-то добавить имя, описание и адрес, как указал автор

Вот сейчас замутил "специфическую" базу данных: 3,3 млн. записей, несколько таблиц, встраиваемые иллюстрации, поиски редактирования. Все живы, без специфики. Хотя базы данных на Питоне для меня новы, эту написал быстро и не напрягаясь. Всё работает мгновенно, пользователи довольны. Ну, если кому-то сложно, если у кого-то "специфика", пусть пишет панду.

Когда сами не знают чего хотят и пишут а125000n, задача не подлежит автоматизации. Вы читать умеете? Я написал исходя из того условия, которое было! Если б я писал условие, я бы пояснил, что an - это неизвестно какая по номеру колонка, а не а15 или а4.

И да, я-то как раз специализируюсь на базах данных. Когда ко мне приходил менеджер и начинал "генерить идею" типа этой: "...создать таблицу с N столбцов, где N вполне может быть сотней?", я ему предлагал "пойти подумать надо моделью процесса", желательно пару лет. Потому что такие базы данных работать не будут.

И вот эта строка: "Замечу также, что an в базах данных, если по уму, возникает только в случае использования n-го количества строк, а не видов полей." мной была написана специально для особо одарённых.

И для очень особо одарённых.  В математике это понимают так. Если не обозначено в условии, что Аn - это последний член бесконечной последовательности, можно, и вполне справедливо, считать, что Аn - это варьируемое число колонок. В одной таблице их может быть 5, в другой 20, в третьей 1. Как спрашивали, так и понято. Потому я сделал оговорку.

Больше не о чем разговаривать. Обычно, как правило, может быть, наверное, мне так кажется... Ещё раз говорю, как сформулировано, так и отвечено. С оговорками. Гипотез не измышляю. Я за 30 лет научился видеть табличные данные в данных и возможности для структурирования их в базе данных достаточно хорошо.

Не знаю кто тут такой сердитый, что без комментариев 4 минуса понаставил. Держите плюс
